# Redis - Loss of old data

Tags: redis

We are using redis for storing cart data. We see that some of the carts that are older than a month aren't available any longer. I assume the data would have been persisted and should be available any time. Are there any settings that I must review to check why some of the old data is getting deleted? There is no TTL set when storing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe It reaches your redis **maxmemory**, take a look at the two config in redis.conf which **maxmemory** and **maxmemory-policy**

When the maxmemory is reached, the redis follows the action specified by maxmemory-policy which could be allkeys-lru or noeviction. if the policy is lru, the older data will be dropped.

as the redis docs said:

> noeviction: return errors when the memory limit was reached and the client is trying to execute commands that could result in more memory to be used (most write commands, but DEL and a few more exceptions).
>
> allkeys-lru: evict keys by trying to remove the less recently used (LRU) keys first, in order to make space for the new data added.

Comment: Thank you . What do the 2 policies do?

Comment: Thanks again. One last question . Does this delete from RAM or disk

Comment: It will be deleted from RAM for new data, and I think redis will update this to rdb or aof (disk) for consistent.

Comment: So even if max memory is reached , the data should still be available in the disk , right ?

Comment: what I means is NO, sorry for my poor English. The data on disk should be consistent with the data in RAM, so when maxmemory is reached, and old data is deleted from redis, In fact, it perform an DEL operation, So the data on disk will also be updated or say deleted.

Comment: sorry , I misunderstood. Thank you so much for explaining patiently!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152335/discussion-between-guangshengzuo-and-punter-vicky).